# Changing Info.plist values via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, plist

I am making my own application and I would like to change some values in my Info.plist file using terminal.

I have tried doing `defaults write Info.plist CFBundleExecutable -string <Executable>` and `defaults write Info.plist CFBundleExecutable <Executable>` however it never seems to work. I don't get any output so I don't even know what it is i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can You try absolute path to Your Info.plist file? It works for me (P.S. after this plist is in binary format)

Comment: That worked! If you add it as a answer I will up-vote and accept it so you get reputation for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `defaults` or `plutil` command line tools.

For `defaults` it looks like this:

```
defaults write /absolute/path/to/Info.plist CFBundleExecutable -string <Executable>
```

For `plutil`:

```
plutil -insert CFBundleExecutable -string <Executable> Info.plist
```

Value after `-insert` is a key path separated by `.`. For example

```
plutil -insert CFBundleDocumentTypes.0.CFBundleTypeExtensions.1 -string "scss" /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

will insert "scss" string deep in the path. Numbers after `.` are for arrays (they are starting with `0`).

Comment: Thanks, but how can you insert into a deeper level of the plist (say add an item to some internal dictionary)? Here you merely present the key, the type and the value - but no key-path.

Comment: @MottiShneor I've added example for deeper key path.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek is it possible to write entire text using defaults write ? meaning full text to a file to replace content with this new text based content?

Comment: @momomo I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by that. Please ask new question with more details.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek It's ok, i solved it. You can convert a text based xml file into a binary plist file. Using that I can edit the xml as I desire from bash, then save/write all of it, rather than just write small pieces of it.

Answer (score 3):

**GET Value - supply raw key**

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleExecutable" Info.plist
```

**SET Value - supply raw key and value**

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set CFBundleExecutable <Executable>" Info.plist
```